# Why footer is not bottom aligned

Tags: flexbox

I learn flexbox by some manuals and trying to repeat example, 
with html code :

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: yellow;
}

footer {
    height: 20vh;   /*you can use pixels e.g. 200px*/;
    background-color: green;
}

header {
    height: 20vh;  /*you can use pixels e.g. 200px*/;
    background-color: blue;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    /*height: calc(100vh - 40vh);*/
    border: 3px dotted red;
    flex: 1;
}
 
aside {
    width: 20vw;
}

nav {
    width: 20vw;
    order: -1;
}

article {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body >
<header>Header</header>
<main>
 <article>Article</article>
 <nav>Nav</nav>
 <aside>Aside</aside>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

you can look at it live :
https://jsfiddle.net/tq6p21jw/
can somebody say why footer is not bottom aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header` and `footer` have fixed height. and you want `main` to take remaining space by setting `display: flex;` and `flex: 1` which is correct. the problem is there is no remaining space to take for `main` because the height of `body` is not set explicitly. so body grows as much as it's contents' height.

giving body a fixed height should solve your problem.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
}
```